# My remove rear function in a linkedDeque is not working

Tags: python-3.x, doubly-linked-list

Hi my remove_rear() is not returning the correct values. My thought process was to loop through to find the node that points to the rear and set it as the new self._rear.

```
def remove_rear(self):
        if self._length<2:
            return None
        elif self._length==1:
            self._rear=temp
        else:
            temp=self._front
            temp2=self._front.get_next()

            while temp2!=None:
                temp=temp.get_next()
                temp2=temp2.get_next()

            self._rear=temp
            temp.set_next(None)
            self._length-=1
            return (temp.get_data())
```

In my driver when I remove the rear and then call get_rear() the node is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the issues:

- In the list has just one element, the first `if` condition is true, and nothing is changed in the list. Yet, a node should be removed...
- The condition of the second `if` condition will never be true, because that case (when length is 1) was already picked up by the first `if` block, where the function was exited. Moreover, this second `if` block references `temp` when it has not yet been defined.
- In the `else` part, `temp` follows one step behind `temp2` and the loop exits when `temp2` is `None`. By consequence, `temp2` will be the rear node when the loop exits. This means this loop was done for nothing, because you already knew what the rear node was: `self._rear=temp` will have no effect, because those two were already equal. The loop should make one less iteration.
- `self._length-=1` is only executed in the `else` block, but should also be executed when the list had only one node.

Here is a correction of your code:

```
    def remove_rear(self):
        if not self._front:
            return None
        # read the value that we will return
        value = self._rear.get_data()
        if self._front == self._rear:
            self._front = self._read = None
        else:
            temp = self._front
            while temp.get_next() != self._rear:  # Compare with rear
                temp = temp.get_next()
            temp.set_next(None)
            self._rear = temp
        # Always reduce length
        self._length -= 1
        return value
```